# cakePHP 1.2/1.3 Manual in CHM format

Tags: cakephp, chm, manual

Can anyone provide me some useful links to download CakePHP 1.2/1.3 Manual including API version in CHM format, which runs locally without any internet usage?

It would be helpful for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a shell plugin that dumps a current copy cookbook as a pdf file: http://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-cookbook-dumper

Answer (score 2):

[GOOGLE DOCS - CakePHP 1.3 Manual - Searchable](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0ByNCj4MHL2TRZTY4N2NhZDQtOGQ5Mi00NGI1LTg1YzktNDI5MjdiN2YyYTRh&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the zip](http://rs292.rapidshare.com/files/323775851/CakePHP12CookbookCHM.zip). I haven't tested it, but it's looking real.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on single html page (downloadable) Cake book and **pdf** generation here: http://leoponton.blogspot.com/2010/07/cakephp-offline-manual.html

Personally, I don't think the Cake book is so big or complex that it justifies the MS clunk of **chm** and anyway the searchability of a single html page is unsurpassed.

Comment: CHM has fulltext search capabilities which are hard to beat, and an keyword index that can be high quality handcrafted

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice compilation of 1.1 and 1.2 Manual and API in this CHM file.  Alas, nothing on 1.3 yet, which would be ideal:

[Link to site that lists CHM contents](http://charupload.wordpress.com/2008/08/17/cakephp-documentation/)

[Direct CHM downloadlink](http://peacech.googlepages.com/cakephp-documentation-080817.chm)